# Dump Query Output is Empty zip file in php

Tags: php, mysql, dump

I am trying to get run dump Query using php,
But is creating 0 byte zip file,
and no db backup is create

****My code is here*******

```
<?php
$dir = "path/to/file/";
$filename = "backup" . date("YmdHis") . ".sql.gz";

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "121";
$db_database = "wp_test";

$cmd = "mysqldump -h {$db_host} -u {$db_username} --password={$db_password} {$db_database} | gzip > {$dir}{$filename}";
exec($cmd);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

passthru("cat {$dir}{$filename}");
?>
```

Comment: you have to check the first MySQL is running with the following command on CMD:

`mysqladmin -u root -p status`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `https://github.com/ajeetku/php-utility-Scripts/blob/master/load.php`

> you need to replace some basic values than you can dump your SQL DB

```
$filename = 'xxxxxx';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'xxxxxxx';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = 'xxxxxxx';
// Database name

$mysql_database = 'xxxxxxx';
```

In your code, you are using php executable command

In that file you can see here All table Codes will be written problematically.
It will be better for you.
 "BEST OF LUCK"